# Only one column after group by()

Tags: python, pandas

Am switch from R to Python for most of my data analysis needs and am running into the following issue. Could be the result of my conceptual understanding of groupby().

I have a Pandas data frame and am trying to summarize the data based on a number of columns. The following code get's me what I want.

```
df = df[(df["Lead Source"] != "chase") & (df["Lead Source"] != "SNE")]
ndf = df[["Date", "Lead Source", "Model Group", "Leads"]].groupby(["Date", "Lead Source"]).sum()
```

[image]

This looked great, but I noticed that there is only one 'real' column when running the following. (fyi ndf2 is just a copy of ndf)

```
ndf2.columns
Out[39]: Index([u'Leads'], dtype='object')
```

Also, the indexing of rows showed that this wasn't quite what I was hoping for.

[image]

How can I adjust the rows so that the column names appear on the first row. The output should look as follows.

```
Date      Lead Source    Leads
1/1/2014  ...            ... 
          ...            ...
          ...            ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
ndf.reset_index()
```

Note that the groupby operation is creating a DataFrame with a [MultiIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex). Since you are grouping by `Date` and `Lead Source`, these are the level names for the MultiIndex. The reason why `Date` and `Lead Source` show up one row below the column names is because Pandas is trying to indicate that these are *index* level names, not columns. (Take a look at `ndf.index.names`.)  The call to [reset_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas-dataframe-reset-index) moves the index levels to columns and renumbers the index.

Or, better yet, use the [`as_index=False` option](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation) when calling `groupby`:

```
ndf = (df[["Date", "Lead Source", "Model Group", "Leads"]]
       .groupby(["Date", "Lead Source"], as_index=False).sum())
```

When aggregating, the `as_index=False` will prevent the grouped values from being used as index values.